# substr issues with a 'Last Updated' value

Tags: php, datetime, substring, substr

I have statistics that require a 'Last Updated' section on a dynamic image, and is expressed in hours. This is done with the following:

```
$lastDate = $StatData->date;
$now = date("Y-m-d G:i:s");
$hours = (strtotime($now) - strtotime($lastDate)) / 3600;
```

Displaying $hours on the image with an imagettftext works just fine. It's just that it's up to 16 characters in length. So to fix that, I attempted the following:

```
if($hours < 10) {
    substr($hours,0,4);
} else {
    substr($hours,0,5);
}
```

The intention was to display no more than two decimals. The result was no change. As if the code wasn't even there.

So my question is one of two: 1: How do i get this to work? 2: I know there is a way to limit the decimal places, without using substr, but what is it? Might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `round()`:

```
$hours = round((strtotime($now) - strtotime($lastDate)) / 3600, 2); // 2 decimals
```

Comment: That did it! I had to modify it a little, because I did need the extra precision in other parts of the script, but I was able to do $lastupdated.' hours ago', where $lastupdated = round($hours, 2). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [number_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
$hours = number_format($hours, 2);
```